# Nest js - httpservice add proxy

Tags: nestjs

I have the next proxy configuration (I just tested it in postman and its working)
host: 'http://tsl.proxyurl.com/standard.pac', port: 8080, protocol: https, no username, no password.

```
And this is my code:
    const options = {
          data,
          'proxy': {
            host: 'http://tsl.proxyurl.com/standard.pac',
            port: 8080
          },
          'headers': {
            'Authorization': `Basic ${base64Auth}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          },
        };
    
        
    const endpoint = `https://api.myrurl.com/st/token`;
    const response = await this.httpService.post(endpoint, data, options).toPromise();
```

But every time, I try, I get:

> message:'Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS
> connection was established'

Someone had a similar issue? How can I fix it?